# How to delete empty cells in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

[This is just a sample I am testing the code in this data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9ETV.png) I have three columns in sheet2. I have to delete the empty cells. This is the updated code which is working for column B only. You can check the snapshot

```
   Sub delete()
   Dim counter As Integer, i As Integer
    counter = 0

  For i = 1 To 10
    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Cells(counter + 1, 2).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
        counter = counter + 1

    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

***Sample screenshot***
[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the sample data?

Comment: is doing nothing is too vague. If you step through the code does `rows` and the `CountA` function show the expected values?

Comment: i have uploaded a sample. @Arul

Comment: @RavindraSinghRawat your code works for me, it delets all rows where there is no data in columns A:C

Comment: r.rows.count=10 when i tried debugging. It is showing the correct count

Comment: I have no idea why it is not working for me. I tried putting it in a separate module. Still nothing happens. @ShaiRado

Comment: Do you mean to delete where there is a blank present? In which case you want If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.rows(i)) < 3 i think

Comment: yes i have to delete that blank cell in between the rows. @QHarr

Comment: @RavindraSinghRawat do you want to deltet entire row of columns A:C where all 3 are empty ? or delete every cell if it's blank ?

Comment: this will help you...
http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/delete-blank-cells.html

Comment: What happens after you delete the cells that are blank? Do the adjacent cells shift left?

Comment: I want to shift the cells in upward direction. When I am running the code noting happens.

Comment: You will be probably be left with some blanks any way. I am guessing you are trying to have blanks as far down the range as possible.

Comment: I have updated as the code now it works for column B

Comment: @AbhinavRawat thanks for sharing the link. It works but only for column B

Comment: @RavindraSinghRawat link is just a ref. you can loop through the complete column while storing all non empty cells; say in an array. and then just paste the array to a column or to any range you want. do the same for other columns also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is to delete the empty cells, give this a try...

```
Sub DeleteBlankCells()
Dim rng As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:C"))
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Comment: @RavindraSinghRawat Your're welcome! Thanks for the feedback. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution but it works.

```
Option Explicit
Sub delete()
Dim rCells As Range, rCell As Range, sFixCell As String

Set rCells = Range("A1:A13")
For Each rCell In rCells
    If rCell = "" Then
        sFixCell = rCell.Address
        Do While rCell.Value = ""
        rCell.delete Shift:=xlUp
        Set rCell = Range(sFixCell)
        Loop
    End If
Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: If I am having multiple blank cells then it not shifts that up. it just shift one cell at a time. @MortenAnthonsen

Comment: It should be fixed now. @RavindraSinghRawat